# How many numbers are there in between 1 and 100 such that they only have 4 divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I found is that if the number factors into two prime numbers, then it's true. Are there any more cases?

Comment: Generally, one says that the only divisors of a prime $p$ are $1$ and $p$, so there are only two. Are you perchance including negative numbers, so that you consider the divisors of a prime $p$ to be $-p,-1,1$ and $p$?

Comment: I meant like if I select 2 and 3 then then the resulting number is 6 and 6 is only having 4 factors....

Comment: Do you mean if the number *factors* into two primes? For instance, $6=2\times3$, and $6$ has four divisors. If that's what you meant, then yes, every number of the form $pq$ for primes $p$ and $q$ has four divisors, namely $1,p,q$, and $pq$. However, you might also want to look at numbers of the form $p^n$.

Comment: Means the numbers raised to the power of 2?

Comment: 1 and 2 respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes. Then the number of divisors of $n$ is $$(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1).$$

What are the possibilities for the exponents $a_i$?